# Implementing a simple chat server

Tags: php, android, chat

I'm going to use XMPPHP to implement a chat service for android clients. In XMPPHP I had to use third party char server like google talk. My question is instead of using third party chat server, is there a simple way to implement my own simple chat server ?

Answer (score 0):

BTW, there are some free Chat servers - e.g. [QuickBlox Chat](http://quickblox.com)

Look at it beautiful Android [Android XMPP Chat sample](http://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample) - also there is video how it [QuickBlox Android Chat video demo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=VKsIhxMaRlE) works.

I implemented some Android applications with Chat, i used QuickBlox - it's simple to understund how to integrate chat into your application using this sample's code & sample's documentation